# Does webrtc currently support streaming of media files?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc

Two questions actually:

1) Does webrtc currently support streaming of historical media files like *.flv and *.ts(HLS) fps to the other end (browser client).  (If you recall, from most of our demos, they use a a live microphone and camera.) If yes, any tutorials or demos on how to do this?

2) Does webrtc allow for a mechanism where we can force a stream to be always tcp and not  attempt udp?feed

Thanks

Comment: This should help give you direction: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) Does webrtc currently support streaming of historical media files like *.flv and *.ts(HLS) fps to the other end (browser client). (If you recall, from most of our demos, they use a a live microphone and camera.) If yes, any tutorials or demos on how to do this?
```

WebRTC doesn't support streaming any file format. WebRTC supports streaming your camera/screen (the screen functionality is still experimental) to another WebRTC enabled client. WebRTC doesn't deal with file streaming or any of the VOD/Live streaming protocols out there (like HLS).

When streaming your camera/screen WebRTC uses Opus as the audio coded and VP8 as the video one. I wouldn't be surprised if support for VP9 is also available on supported platforms.

If you want to stream HLS through a WebRTC you could potentially use the data channel and then use the MSE API or Flash for video playback. Here is a project that does exactly does http://viblast.com/.

```
2) Does webrtc allow for a mechanism where we can force a stream to be always tcp and not attempt udp?feed
```

The short answer is no. WebRTC uses a set of protocols (RTP/SRTP) based on UDP. UDP is widely believed to be better suited for video chats (and other similar projects) than TCP.